# MongoDB bulk.execute() promise neither resolves nor rejects and bulkWriteResult isn't being returned

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, mongodb-query

MongoDB version 3.6.7, mongoDB node.js driver version 3.1.10.

Have a function which should add some data to the db in a bulk unordered operation. When `bulk.execute()` is called the data is inserted into the DB as have manually checked this is the case, however the `bulkWriteResult` object which should be generated as a result of the execution isn't being returned.

We need that for use in other functions to determine the number of insertions etc. So when the function in question is chained in other functions it returns undefined, when adding `bulk.execute().then(console.log)` also nothing is logged to the terminal.

The function takes 3 parameters, the MongoClient, the name of the collection and the documents to be inserted into the DB which is an array of documents.

Have also tried adding err and result callbacks too with no luck, none of the console.logs are reached.

```
batch.execute((err, result) => {
    console.log('RESULT INSERTED:', result.nInserted)
    console.log('RESULT ERRORS:', result.getWriteErrorCount())
    console.log('RESULT INSIGHTS:', result.getWriteErrors())
    console.log('ERROR:', err)
})
```

Any ideas why the `bulkWriteResult` would not be returned yet the bulk insertion is successful?, function was working and returning the expected object prior to upgrading the mongoDB node driver to 3.1.10.

```
const insertManyMissingEntries = (database, collectionName, documents) => {
  const db = database.db('data')
  const collection = db.collection(collectionName)
  const batch = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
  documents.forEach(doc => {
    batch
      .find({ year: doc.year, month: doc.month, code: doc.code })
      .upsert()
      .updateOne({ '$setOnInsert': doc })
  })

  return batch.execute()
}
```

Comment: What is your Mongoose version?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "csv": "2.0.0",
    "csv-parse": "2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6"
  },
  "engineStrict": true
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "commander": "^2.9.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "mocha": "5.1.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.10",
    "nock": "^9.0.2",
    "nodemon": "1.17.5",
    "promise-limit": "^2.2.0",
    "request": "^2.75.0",
    "sinon": "^4.3.0",
    "standard": "^8.0.0",
    "watch": "^0.19.2"
  }

Comment: No mongoose in use here, but package.json dependencies and dev dependencies above, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't a way to resolve this issue though we believe it was caused by a docker mongo image version not being the official one or out of date. Even the folks at mongoDB weren't able to replicate this or explain any circumstances where a promise should fail to either resolve or reject within the timescales the functions were working to so like many things it remains a mystery that we had to workaround by basically using a ternary to handle the `undefined` that resulted from the promise error without ever actually solving the underlying issue - not ideal or best practice but in absence of other options it's what we did.

Thanks for everyone's help and comments to try to resolve it, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your function

```
const insertManyMissingEntries = (database, collectionName, documents) => {

    if (documents.length === 0)
        return Promise.reject('documents length is zero')

    const operations = documents.map((doc) => {

        const filter = {year: doc.year, month: doc.month, code: doc.code}
        const update = {$setOnInsert: doc}

        return {updateOne: {'filter': filter, 'update': update, 'upsert': true}}
    })

    const db = database.db('data')
    const collection = db.collection(collectionName)

    const bulkOptions = {ordered: false}

    return collection.bulkWrite(operations, bulkOptions)
}
```

If documents parameters is empty i.e. length = 0 the collection bulk write function will always fail. Watch it.
Also you need to make sure you have index on fields year, month, code or your bulk will be executing slow because it will every time it will perform a collection scan to find a document.

Remember,
driver docs is your best friend
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately that still returns the same behaviour as the original code with .then((result) => { console.log(result)}) never being accessible as, the promise is still unresolved and un-rejected

Comment: Limited as to what can be shared due to company policy, when i replaced the original function with your suggested code, ran it, the same result was experienced.

When this function is used in another function chain combined with a .then() as below, insertManyMissingEntries(database, collectionName, blankDocuments).then(insertionMeta => {
        const totalInsertions = insertionMeta.reduce((total, meta) => total + meta.nUpserted, 0)

There is a catch() for errors which outputs Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined. So the same issue unresolved/un rejected promise

Comment: insertManyMissingEntries  is not returning a promise you cannot then it. I update the answer, try again.

Comment: What insertManyMissingEntries should be returning is the bulkWriteResult object from the bulk.execute() method which should return a promise if no callback is passed according to the driver docs. I've just no clue as to why it neither resolves or rejects. Also the documents parameter for the function is an array containing valid formed DB documents as have logged that out too.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not permitted by company to share much more than i am, however this function on it's own should be returning a result or rejecting and was working successfully until we had to upgrade mongoDB driver (downgrading is an unlikely option). Would you know of any reasons why a off the shelf promise such as execute() would not resolve or reject and just hang?